# how to convert string from div attribute to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i try convert a string to object. i use :

```
var ec = $(".selector").attr('build'); // this return {abc:'one', bcm:'two', etc...}
var et = ec.abc // this return me undefined
```

i try this way

```
var et = new Object(ec);
var t = et.abc // this return undefined
```

How can convert this ??

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to go back and mark some of your previous questions as answered, it will make people more apt to assisting you.

Answer (score 5):

If that attribute contains a `string` that just happens to be in the format of a Json object, you have to parse the `string` first to be able to access elements of it in a way that you would working with Json:

```
var ec = $(".selector").attr('build');
var myObject = JSON.parse(ec);
var et = myObject.abc;
```

Of course you might want to add validation around that `string` to make sure it's always going to be in that form, otherwise you could run into issues by making those sorts of assumptions.

Also, is there a reason you are storing a Json string in an HTML attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.parse()` method

```
var et= $.parse($(".selector").attr('build'));
var t = et.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

If this

`var ec = $(".selector").attr('build');`

returns this

```
// this return {abc:'one', bcm:'two', etc...}
```

then you already have an object.

Comment: See the answer from @slandau.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string using a JSON parser. You can't just pass the string to the `Object` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `attr()`, try using the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method, which will allow you to store object, not just strings.

When you store your object, use the following syntax:

```
var d = {abc:'one', bcm:'two'};
$(".selector").data('build', d);
```

Then, when you need to retrieve your object, use:

```
var d = $(".selector").data('build');
//access properties
var x = d.abc;
```

Otherwise, if you use `attr()`, you will need to parse the result into an object, which you can use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) for.